# Better performing way of of looking up documents with ids NOT in list and sorting on some publish date

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have tried below code, however performance tests have shown, requests are on the order of a second or more per request. I would like to be 10 times better than that. I suspect it is doing a full scan due to the NOT. Is there a way to make the NOT $in run faster? Maybe rewriting it into something else? I tried using a $lookup to join a temporary collection with the regular one, however that was even slower, due to having to create new collection, insert data, run the $lookup query then delete the temporary collection again. I guess there is no such thing as a "negative" index, or is there?.

```
const filter = {
         state: "Live",
         id: { $not: { $in: ids } },
         "type": "Message",
       };
const docs = await MyModel.find(filter, { _id: 0, __v: 0 })
         .sort({ "live_date": -1 })
         .lean();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating an index on `{state:1, type:1, live_date:1, id:1}`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, yes there is already an index on these. Regular lookups without the NOT are very fast.

Comment: Check using explain with executionStats to see what is taking the time

Comment: Does using [`$nin`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) instead help to improve performance? `id: {$nin: ids}`

Answer (score 0):

First, definitely check the query plan using explain().

If it's bad, maybe try hint() and see if that helps.

If you're on the latest releases and the query optimizer is not being "smart" in its handling of $not : $in, consider opening a jira ticket?

Is your cardinality really such that not in with an index is better?  i.e. weeding out a small percentage of items with an index doesn't improve performance in a database.

Also, consider using/adding limit()?  Do you really want all the results or just the first page?  Sometimes this makes a big difference.  And for a typical data distribution query, $not : $in should return most of the collection so if it's huge that's a lot?